# If not using user data, how to search simple artist information in the Spotify Web API?

Tags: spotify

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get simple artist info. Thats all my app really needs to do, I don't intend to ever get any user data.
I saw Spotify has an example on: 
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/

Should their 'Search for an Artist (and Lookup) Demo' jsfiddle example work 'as is':
http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/0u0v7e1b/
Seems like that code doesn't do any authentication code (it just seems to '401 authorized' error in the browser so not sure why Spotify would post that as an official working demo example). 
I'll post the JS code at bottom of this post.
But I thought maybe for non-user-centric information maybe we do not need to do any authentication (other than passing a simple api key like other apis like SongKick/LastFM). At least thats what i was hoping.

Can anyone help make a JSFiddle that works? (one where I can supply pretend my api key and the example can then run).

```
// find template and compile it
var templateSource = document.getElementById('results-template').innerHTML,
    template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource),
    resultsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('results'),
    playingCssClass = 'playing',
    audioObject = null;

var fetchTracks = function (albumId, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/' + albumId,
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
};

var searchAlbums = function (query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
        data: {
            q: query,
            type: 'album'
        },
        success: function (response) {
            resultsPlaceholder.innerHTML = template(response);
        }
    });
};

results.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (target !== null && target.classList.contains('cover')) {
        if (target.classList.contains(playingCssClass)) {
            audioObject.pause();
        } else {
            if (audioObject) {
                audioObject.pause();
            }
            fetchTracks(target.getAttribute('data-album-id'), function (data) {
                audioObject = new Audio(data.tracks.items[0].preview_url);
                audioObject.play();
                target.classList.add(playingCssClass);
                audioObject.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                    target.classList.remove(playingCssClass);
                });
                audioObject.addEventListener('pause', function () {
                    target.classList.remove(playingCssClass);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});

document.getElementById('search-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchAlbums(document.getElementById('query').value);
}, false);
```